# What is a Virtual IP (VIP)?

Tags: ipv4, ip

I heard a lot about **virtual IPs** (VIP) in WAF, VPS, NAT... but I still can't understand its concept.
What is a Virtual IP (VIP) ? and how it differs practically from a Public IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this depends on context. Usually, *virtual* means that the IP address is not assigned on a permanent basis but may move around. A virtual IP address can be a public address or a private address.

One example is a content delivery web cluster. On the public side it's got a pool of virtual IPs that one or more load balancers map to the servers' DMZ addresses. Under normal load there is a 1:1 mapping, so that a virtual address is always forwarded to the same DMZ address. However, when a server crashes or exceeds normal load the load balancer moves the mapping over to another server.

Some vendors also call addresses that are mapped over destination NAT *virtual IPs* (e.g. Fortinet). This is the same as *port forwarding*.

Comment: so the CDN act as a load balancer and give its own IP to the client who want to contact the actual server, this IP is called then VIP.  
I have another question please, if the actual server has a public IP, can we bypass the CDN/VIP layer and contact the server directly ?

Comment: I'm not really getting your first sentence, but yes, usually the server has at least one static, dedicated IP address that is used for monitoring and administration.